# Need a Router Recommendation

Tags: router, firewall

I am running 24*7 Web Service. So my server is expected to be connected at Internet always. I am using now CISCO 2800 router model. It just working fine. My all server boxes are Linux Machines. But Its there very hard time with my Internet Service Provider. Sometimes Its get disconnected. So I thought to buy a Secondary line from an another Internet Service Provider and connect to a New Router. I am not a System Admin Guy. Moreover I didn't have any firewalls for my servers. And I am thinking to have my routers configured as below,

- One Primary Router(Typically new Router) connected to an one ISP with Static IP. It should serve for all my servers.
- One Secondary Router(Old Cisco 2800) connected to an another ISP with Static Ip. It should serve for all my local machines. So that our local browsing will not affect upload bandwidth of my servers.

OK. What If ISP connected in Primary Router is get disconnected from online. In this case, The Secondary Router should get alive for my servers too.

1) Could I do this configuartion through Routers? If I could do, then what Router should I buy?

2) Is there a Router will come with Firewall? What Firewall is best for my Linux Servers. I don't know much about Firewall. I just want some recommendations.

It is a server Related question. So I posted it earlier in [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com). But Someone told me to post this question here. Give your feedbacks Instead of giving Negatives

Comment: Or how about a single multi-wan router with failover?   Also, “the secondary router should get alive for my servers too” is a separate (yet related) DNS issue.

Comment: Actually rethinking, you’d want load-balanced instead of failover, and the public DNS records for your websites with multiple A records.   I added a multi-wan router with failover but my need is a bit different, and my second isp is a cellular modem.

Comment: By the way, dual wan is easier and cheaper than you probably expect.